# RxSwift Combining heterogeneous observables

Tags: rx-swift, combinelatest

I have two objects Chat and messages both in Realm database. I am fetching from db and getting two observables. Message object have chatId through which I can get chat object. 
chats() - gives Observable<[Chat>
messages() - gives Observable<[Messages>

The problem is when I use map function on messages(), I get chatId, now I need chat array to filter the chatId and get chat object.

How can I do that? Can I combine both observables and get emitted both array in single closure. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, you want to use either `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom`.

I don't quite understand the context because you say you have an `Observable<[Message]>`, but you are getting a single `chatID` from that array. I would expect you to get an array of chat IDs.

Comment: yes you are right. I did using combinedLatest.         let combineObservable: Observable<([Chat], [Message])> = Observable.combineLatest(useCases.output.chats(), useCases.output.allMessages())